# Aliasing "Type" entry of normal JSON to "@type", when value of "Type" is a JSON object

Tags: json-ld

I want to store a normal JSON to a triple store. The normal JSON has its own format for Ids and Types:

```
{
  "Id": "123456",
  "Type": {
    "Id": "7890",
    "Name": "Person",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I am able to flatten the document and give the value of "Id" the type "@id", using a custom context. I am stuck trying to alias "Type" to "@type".

Is there a way to use the "Type" entry of the normal JSON as an "@type" keyword using only a custom context?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by aliasing "Type" to "@type", since your example would not be valid JSON-LD if "Id" was replaced with "@id" and "Type" was replaced with "@type".

But could perhaps a context like this would be what you are looking for?

```
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.org/things/",
    "Id": "@id",
    "Type": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
    "Name": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
  }
```

[Example](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fthings%2F%22%2C%22Id%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%22%2C%22Name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%7D%2C%22Id%22%3A%22123456%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%7B%22Id%22%3A%227890%22%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Person%22%7D%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%7D) in JSON-LD Playground.

Or, if the different ids come from different namespaces, perhaps with [scoped contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#scoped-contexts):

```
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "@base": "http://example.org/objects/",
    "Id": "@id",
    "Type": {
      "@id": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
      "@context": {
        "@base": "http://example.org/types/",
        "Name": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
      }
    }
```

[Also](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40version%22%3A1.1%2C%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fobjects%2F%22%2C%22Id%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%22%2C%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Ftypes%2F%22%2C%22Name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%22Id%22%3A%22123456%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%7B%22Id%22%3A%227890%22%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Person%22%7D%7D) in JSON-LD Playground.